# How can i solve the error oftenly my menu script collapsed.

Tags: magento-1.9, menu, script

Am using magento sample data theme and changed menu block. How can i solve oftenly my menu script collapse. i am using [this](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/responsive-custom-menu.html) menu.

[image]

Comment: Am updated my question.